# Cannot install ruby on MAC 10.11.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I cannot install ruby new version. I stall the home-brew and ruby-build, both install successful. I type $ rbenv, it shows

...

install          Install a Ruby version using ruby-build

...

then i stall version 2.3.1

`$ rbenv install 2.3.1`

it shows error

```
Zhimings-MacBook-Pro:~ zhimingjiang$ rbenv install 2.3.1
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...
mkdir: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib: Permission denied

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.5 using ruby-build 20160426)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/wf/tkkf34w562q8mqb59f43lnrh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160703231044.15035
Results logged to /var/folders/wf/tkkf34w562q8mqb59f43lnrh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160703231044.15035.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/wf/tkkf34w562q8mqb59f43lnrh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160703231044.15035 ~
/var/folders/wf/tkkf34w562q8mqb59f43lnrh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160703231044.15035/ruby-2.3.1 /var/folders/wf/tkkf34w562q8mqb59f43lnrh0000gn/T/ruby-build.20160703231044.15035 ~
```

I does't have path `/usr/local/var/rbenv`, I only have path `/usr/local/rbenv`

Additions (here is the tutorial i have watched
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx0NrIbQbzI)

Comment: use rvm to install ruby http://rvm.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try install `ruby` via `rbenv` following as this tutorial:

I tried it and success.

[install rbenv on osx](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan)

Update:

You should do these steps as below:

```
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you used rbenv to install ruby. First, find the desired version:

```
rbenv install -l
```

And `rbenv install 2.3.1`

Comment: I tried, same message appear...                                                          Installing ruby-2.3.1...
mkdir: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib: Permission denied

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.5 using ruby-build 20160426)

Comment: I figure out in other way.

Comment: I think your approach is correct too. however I change .bash_profile by mistake.  So, doesn't work for me. But I will still mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I find out

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

search key words "Building from Source"

follow the instruction 
download -> unzip -> terminal cd into folder -> star to type those 3 line commend.

also if install other which require ruby. You may still need to type $./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl